# Image center inside multiple divs CSS

Tags: css, html

I need to center images inside of multiple divs. Everything I try breaks.

These are four boxes, alternating red & blue - horizontal. Looking to have them centered in the page and pushed to the top under another div block. Within each block is an image, which is centered to the same % margin on all sides to the relative red or blue box. You can see below I tried both placing the image directly in a redbox/bluebox div or even going one layer deeper with a box just for the image.

4 Box Example - HTML:

```html
<div id="box-container">
  <!-- Trying natively within a box -->
  <div class="bluebox">
    <img src="images/1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="redbox">
    <!-- Trying one-layer deeper with its own div -->
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="images/2.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bluebox">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="images/3.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="redbox">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="images/4.png">
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```css
box-container {
  height: 900px;
  width: 950px;
  padding: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.bluebox {
  height: 150px;
  width: 170px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.redbox {
  height: 150px;
  width: 170px;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.thumbnail img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 130px;
  width: 150px;
}



<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<div id="box-container">
  <!-- Trying natively within a box -->
 <div class="bluebox">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="redbox">
    <!-- Trying one-layer deeper with its own div -->
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bluebox">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="redbox">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can we see a fiddle or snippet?

Comment: @CarlJan not sure what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add padding to the image based on the height of your thumbnail div.

```
.thumbnail img {
  display: block;
  height: 130px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;

}
```

Comment: That fixed half the problem - the pictures are now centered. How do I take the whole #boxcontainer and move it to center?

Comment: #box-container{text-align: center;} it will center all of them.

Answer (score 1):

```
.bluebox img, .redbox .thumbnail img, .bluebox .thumbnail img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

or

```
.bluebox, .redbox .thumbnail, .bluebox .thumbnail {
  text-align: center;
}
```

using flexbox

```
.bluebox, .redbox .thumbnail, .bluebox .thumbnail {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Try to change the image width. You will see the difference between the selected answer and my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have what you are looking for in this here JSFiddle I just wipped up:  https://jsfiddle.net/9yLspwr6/5/

A few key points before the code...

1. In order to have all the div elements 'float' left you ahve to apply div.className{float:left;}  This will ensure divs float left to right and wrap around if they run out of space (much like a paragraph of text).  More on CSS float property here:  https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp
2. Vertical margin does not support 'margin:auto;' like it does for horizontal.  Margin can be defined by div.ClassName{margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;} OR div.className{margin:0px auto;}.  The first element this way is for top/bottom margin.  The second is for left/right margin.  I had to use a little math to vertically center your images, but it gets you what you need.  Here is some good documentation on margin:  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_margin.asp
3. Cleaned up the HTML and removed some CSS no longer needed.  I did this to simplify the code while maintaining the solution.  If you drop this code into a site you'll want to ensure you only target only the appropriate tags.  For example - my code is targeting ALL img tags.  You would want to put a class or ID on the IMG tags you want and then ensure that is reflected in the CSS.

I modified the HTML quite a bit.  Removed much of the unnecessary elements that were in place for troubleshooting.

```
  <div class="bluebox">
    <img src="images/1.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="redbox">
      <img src="images/2.png">
  </div>

  <div class="bluebox">
      <img src="images/3.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="redbox">
      <img src="images/4.png">
  </div>
```

Modified CSS below:

```
.bluebox {
  height: 150px;
  width: 170px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid black;
  float:left; // new.  essentially left justifies the divs.
}

.redbox {
  height: 150px;
  width: 170px;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid black;
  float:left; // new
}

img { // simplified the target.  wrap entire contents of the HTML with a different DIV id to target only images within that div
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto; // added 10px.  it will then apply 10px margin to top and bottom, auto on left/right
  height: 130px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

That should do it.  Hope it helps!